Trouble building a drive axle with steering
I am having trouble with getting a differential and a rack-and-pinion steering mechanism to work together without being unstable or inaccurate. I don’t have the special wheels (rims/tires), ball joints, or caster pieces to make any other design, so avoiding those would be ideal.

What is exactly the problem you're facing? How is the steering unstable or inaccurate? Can you share what you have tried so far (a photo would be the best or a digital build), and how does that not fulfill the expectations?

I would like to, but I’m using my phone, so I can’t download or drag photos.

On phone you can tap the image icon in the editor, then select "Browse" and pick a photo from your phone's gallery to paste.

I did it! That was a lot easier than I thought! I hooked up the wheels directly to the rack and pinion, and universal joints to the wheels on both sides

Great news! If you could add photos or descriptions of what the problem was and how you managed to fix it, that could be a worthy contribution to the site - since the goal is to build a repository of knowledge for future visitors.
